# Can't find WebElement with a CSS selector using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to access a `WebElement` on the [website](https://dbz.space/cards) after a previous html element has been clicked. When you load the website you'll see a grid of objects (which for this question's context let's call them cards). If you inspect the page before clicking on anything, you'll see that under the `body > div.view > section.list.gi` div, there are multiple divs which belong to the class `item.card`. As you can see in my code below, i get the first card object that belongs to that class using the `firstCard` selector. I then call the `.click()` method to simulate the click and wait for a few seconds. After that though, is where i'm having trouble. I want to access the `base` attribute of the selected card which is located inside the `"body > div.overlay > div#cards"+base + " > div.one.card"` div's tags. After some searching around, i found that the `id` of each card object inside the `div.overlay` (after the user has clicked on the card when the website first loaded) is the string `cards` + the `base` string you see above. Now the `base` string is an attribute of each card object (before clicking on it when the website first loaded) so i retrieve that value and store it in the `String base` field. So when i try to access the "base" attribute of the first card after clicking on it's icon at the beginning using the `dataSelector` field, i get an error that the element doesn't exist but the `dataSelector`'s value is `body > div.overlay > div#cards1018031 > div.one.card` which looks fine to me. Any ideas on why it can't find the element?

myClass.java:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String url = "https://dbz.space/cards/"; // The website to read data from

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"C:/Users/Steli/OneDrive/Documents/PhantomJS/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
        driver.get(url); // Connect to the url
        //WebElement button = driver.findElement(new By.ByCssSelector("body > div.view > section.more > div.content > div.btn.mat")); // Get the Show more Button element

        String firstCard = "body > div.view > section.list.gi > div.item.card";
        WebElement card = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(firstCard));
        String base = card.getAttribute("base");

        if(isClickable(card,driver)) {
            card.click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            String dataSelector = "body > div.overlay > div#cards"+base + " > div.one.card";// + " > div.one.card > div.common > div.stats > div > div.stat";
            System.out.println(dataSelector);
            WebElement data = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(dataSelector));
            System.out.println(data.getAttribute("base"));
        }

    }
```

P.S: The `isClickable()` method is implemented as follows :

```
private static boolean isClickable(WebElement el, WebDriver driver) {
        try{
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 6);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(el));
            //System.out.println("clickable!");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is working fine with chrome WebDriver.

Comment: @KunduK could you please post the code using ChromeDriver?

Answer (score 0):

I have just copied your code and paste there to check with chrome driver and its working fine.However instead of sleep you can use explicit wait. `WebDriverWait`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Software\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://dbz.space/cards/"); 
            String firstCard = "body > div.view > section.list.gi > div.item.card";
            WebElement card = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(firstCard));
            String base = card.getAttribute("base");
            card.click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            String dataSelector = "body > div.overlay > div#cards"+base + " > div.one.card";// + " > div.one.card > div.common > div.stats > div > div.stat";
            System.out.println(dataSelector);
            WebElement data = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(dataSelector));
            System.out.println(data.getAttribute("base"));

}
```

Output On my console:

[image]

---

Instead of sleep use WebDriverWait.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Software\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://dbz.space/cards/"); 
        String firstCard = "body > div.view > section.list.gi > div.item.card";
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
        WebElement card=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(firstCard)));
        String base = card.getAttribute("base");
        card.click();

        String dataSelector = "body > div.overlay > div#cards"+base + " > div.one.card";
        System.out.println(dataSelector);
        WebElement data =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(dataSelector)));
        System.out.println(data.getAttribute("base"));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, i have the same exact thing but i'm getting a `Timed out connecting to chrome..Retrying..` and an exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault()'`. I've set the driver path to the executable and chrome is on the latest version. Does that mean that there is no default contsructor?

Comment: download latest selenium jar and add those jar into build path.

Comment: I've got version 3.141.59 installed which is the latest client version right? At least from what i'm seeing on their website

Comment: Yes you are right that one is latest.so you have both chrome driver and chrome version are latest right?

Comment: Yup, chrome driver and chrome v. 77.0.3865.120

Comment: Please go that link and down load latest compatible version of chrome driver wrt chrome version installed on your machine. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: Shouldn’t creat any problem then.Strange I do have the all configuration you have.is your Java is very old?just curious.

Comment: java is on version 11.04 and the sadly i already have the latest version of chrome driver from that exact site

Comment: Just check that error on google and see if you get any solution over there?

Comment: Ill keep on looking but no luck so far

Comment: Looks like i had to include the server .jar file from selenium to make it work. Now everything works fine